# Как не повторять запрос к сервису при переходе между страницами

Tags: flutter, dart

Ситуация: При авторизации пользователя происходит запрос к веб сервису, веб сервис возвращает json ответ который через Navigator передается на домашнюю(Stateful) страницу приложения, из данных рисуется список виджетов. 
Вопрос: как сделать так чтобы при переходе с домашней страницы и обратно(например: home page->settings->home page) не требовалось делать повторного запроса к веб сервису для получения данных, чтобы потом снова "превратить" их в виджеты. То есть как сделать запрос к сервису всего один раз, и обращаться к результатам ответа сервиса в любой момент и из любого места?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов решить вашу проблему:

1. Реализовать [паттерн Singleton (Одиночка)](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/singleton) — это паттерн проектирования, который гарантирует, что у класса есть только один экземпляр, и предоставляет к нему глобальную точку доступа.
2. Использовать [Dependency Injection (Внедрение зависимости)](https://medium.com/@xufocoder/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-de1367295ba8) — это такая техника, где посредством одного объекта (или статического метода) предоставляются зависимости другого объекта. Зависимость — это объект, который может быть использован (как сервис).

---

Реализация **Singleton** (*с помощью factory конструктора*):

```
class Singleton {
  static final Singleton _singleton = Singleton._internal();

  factory Singleton() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  Singleton._internal();

  int a;
  int b;
}

main() {
  var s1 = Singleton();
  var s2 = Singleton();
  print(identical(s1, s2));  // true
  print(s1 == s2);           // true

  s1.a = 10;
  s2.b = 20;

  print(s1.a + s1.b); // 30
  print(s2.a + s2.b); // 30
}
```

---

Для реализации **Dependency Injection** я рекомендую использовать уже готовы библиотеки:

1. [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-readme-tab-) предоставляет зависимости через дерево виджетов.
2. [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it#-readme-tab-) предоставляет зависимости через созданный сервис.
3. [Inject](https://github.com/google/inject.dart) DI похожий на [Dagger](https://dagger.dev/).

Все DI библиотеки необходимо изучать и понимать как работают, чтобы начать разрабатывать с помощью них. Эта тема сложная для новичка, по этому рекомендую использовать **Singleton**.